# Html code in inspect element differs from html source code

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, web-crawler

I am trying to crawl a website (with python) and get its users info. But when I download the source of the pages, it is different from what I see in inspect element in chrome. I googled and it seems I should use selenium, but I don't know how to use it. This is the code I have and when I see the `driver.page_source`  it is still the source page as in chrome and doesn't look like the source in inspect element.
I really appreciate if someone can help me to fix this.

```
import os
from selenium import webdriver

chromedriver = "/Users/adam/Downloads/chromedriver"
os.environ["webdriver.chrome.driver"] = chromedriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)
driver.get("http://www.tudiabetes.org/forum/users/Bug74/activity")
driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 2):

It's called `XHR`.
Your page was loaded from another call, (your url only loads the strcuture of the page, and the meat of the page comes from a different source using XHR, json formatted string) not the pageload it self.

You should really consider using `requests` and `bs4` to query [this page](http://www.tudiabetes.org/forum/user_actions.json?offset=0&username=bug74&filter=4,5&_=1442244698245) instead.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But still it's not similar to inspect element code. I'm trying to find the date user has joined. But I can't.

Comment: @Erin the date is in the JavaScript section of the page `created_at":"2009-07-15T23` I suggest you study `requests` and `bs4`

Comment: Thanks  @taesu. This solved the problem of seeing the joined date. I was hoping to get something similar to the html code in inspect element though.